# Accessing C array in golang

Tags: python, go, ctypes

I have two files, `module.go` and `test.py`. My goal is to speed up some calculations that is done in python, but have an issue accessing array of integers in go.

`module.go`

```
package main

import "C"

//export Example
func Example(testArray []C.int) C.int {
    return testArray[2]
}

func main() {}
```

and simple test file in python:

```
from ctypes import *

# Load compiled go module
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("./gomodule.so")
# We are passing an array of 256 elements and recieving integer
lib.Example.argtypes = [c_int * 256]
lib.Example.restype = c_int
pyarr = [x for x in range(256)]
# Make C array from py array
arr = (c_int * len(pyarr))(*pyarr)
print lib.Example(arr)
```

After compiling go module with `go build -buildmode=c-shared -o gomodule.so module.go` and fire up python file I got:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x12 pc=0x7fb18b6e688c]

goroutine 17 [running, locked to thread]:
main.Example(...)
        /home/metro/go/src/github.com/golubaca/carinago/module.go:7
main._cgoexpwrap_53c1c00d0ad3_Example(0xa, 0x7fff33a2eac0, 0x7fff33a2ea70, 0x722a921de6cae100)
        _cgo_gotypes.go:47 +0x1c
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I get that C array is different from Go, but can't find any tutorial how to access it's values without panic.

Comment: As a suggestion, have you looked at numpy? (i will openly admit i have no idea what is happening in this code here. However, calculations on "array of integers" sounds like numpy department. It has helped me a lot with speeding up calculations)

Comment: Yeah, i have,but I would like to use go because of some other code I have already, and I would like to integrate license check in go as `.so` file, because it's at least little harder to reverse engeneer than plain python file or pyc. So main idea here is to use license check with critical part of code in go, and compile it together.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the idiomatic, efficient Go solution (avoid reflection).

`module.go`:

```
package main

import "C"

import "unsafe"

//export Example
func Example(cArray *C.int, cSize C.int, i C.int) C.int {
    gSlice := (*[1 << 30]C.int)(unsafe.Pointer(cArray))[:cSize:cSize]
    return gSlice[i]
}

func main() {}
```

`test.py`:

```
from ctypes import *

# Load compiled go module
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("./gomodule.so")
# We are passing an array of 256 elements and receiving an integer
lib.Example.argtypes = [c_int * 256]
lib.Example.restype = c_int
pyarr = [x for x in range(256)]
# Make C array from py array
arr = (c_int * len(pyarr))(*pyarr)
print(lib.Example(arr, len(arr), 4))
```

Output:

```
$ go build -buildmode=c-shared -o gomodule.so module.go
$ python test.py
4
$
```

Comment: Nice, I tried this and the result is the same as the first answer, but file size of the shared object is smaller which is great. I must accept this as an "accepted" answer because of efficient conversion. Many thanks to both of you.

Comment: What is the point of the `[1 << 30]` bitwise? Could you add some information explaining what exactly is going on here?

Comment: @NathanF.: the Go array must have a declared size. This sets the maximum allowed size and capacity of the slice. Go will construct the actual slice header from the parameters, and use the base of the array as the underlying array. So if the array actually has 256 `C.int`s in it, the slice will have that as its length and capacity and Go won't access outside the actual array.

Answer (score 3):

An array in C cannot be automatically casted to a slice in Go. Note that in Go, a slice has two parts: a length, and a pointer to the backing data.

So you would have to manually create the slice from the pointer.

```
package main

import (
    "C"
    "reflect"
    "unsafe"
)

//export Example
func Example(carr *C.int, size int, idx int) C.int {

    // Build the slice manually using unsafe
    var slice []C.int
    header := (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&slice))
    header.Cap = size
    header.Len = size
    header.Data = uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(carr))

    return slice[idx]
}

func main() {}
```

Then you would call the Go exported function in your python code like:

```
from ctypes import *

# Load compiled go module
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("./gomodule.so")
# We are passing an array of 256 elements and recieving integer
lib.Example.argtypes = [c_int * 256]
lib.Example.restype = c_int
pyarr = [x for x in range(256)]
# Make C array from py array
arr = (c_int * len(pyarr))(*pyarr)
print lib.Example(arr, len(arr), 4)
```

The example above should print the 4th index element of the array

Comment: This is the right answer. I didn't think of headers, but now I know what to look for other types as well. Thanks a lot!