# What is proper Ctypes to pass array

Tags: python, go, ctypes

I have a Go function which gets an array as input parameters and simply print them to the console:

```
package main
import "C"
func testArray(xs []float64) {
for arg := range xs {
            fmt.Println(arg)
        }
}
```

I want to call the function from my python code, I'm trying to use Ctypes, but I didn't find the proper Ctypes for passing an array. This is my python code:

```
from ctypes import *
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("./main.so")
print ("Loaded go generated SO library")
lib.testArray.argtypes = [?]
arr =[1, 3, .5, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, .5, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1]
lib.testArray(arr)
```

I'm going to find the proper Ctypes to put instead of "question mark" to make my code work properly.

Comment: Can you try with `lib.testArray.argtypes = POINTER(c_float)`. Note that both `POINTER` and `c_float` has to be imported from `ctypes` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* hook your Go code to Python code, but to make it accessible from Python, you must `//export` the Go function.

You *cannot* pass a slice directly to the Go code.  You must fake this out with a Go array, to which you add a slice header using a conversion in the exported function that is called from the C or Python code.  [peterSO's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53242629/1256452) to the related question [Accessing C array in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53238602/1256452) shows how to do it using `unsafe.Pointer` (though for `int` rather than `float64`).  I'm a bit suspicious of the hardcoded array size here breaking in some future Go implementation, but it certainly works today.  (There may be an 8 GB size limit on the C array here as well.)

Hence (tested now):

```
package main

import "C"

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

//export CTestArray
func CTestArray(xsBase *C.double, n C.int) {
    xs := (*[1 << 30]float64)(unsafe.Pointer(xsBase))[:n:n]
    testArray(xs)
}

func testArray(xs []float64) {
    for _, arg := range xs {
        fmt.Println(arg)
    }
}

func main() {}
```

(You technically don't need the intermediate function: the `testArray` code can just appear after creating the slice variable.  But I would recommend a wrapper construct so that your Go-only code does not use `unsafe`: all the potential horrible bugs are confined to the wrapper.)

The remaining tricky part is building the array in Python, and passing it.  You must encode the actual size.  Fortunately, it seems to be OK to keep resetting `argtypes`:

```
from ctypes import *
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("./main.so")
print ("Loaded go generated SO library")
lib.CTestArray.restype = None
l = [1, 3, .5, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, .5, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1]
arr = (c_double * len(l))(*l)
lib.CTestArray.argtypes = [type(arr), c_int]
lib.CTestArray(arr, len(arr))
print("done 1")

l = [42, 3.1415]
arr = (c_double * len(l))(*l)
lib.CTestArray.argtypes = [type(arr), c_int]
lib.CTestArray(arr, len(arr))
print("done 2")

l = [i/2 for i in range(40)]
arr = (c_double * len(l))(*l)
lib.CTestArray.argtypes = [type(arr), c_int]
lib.CTestArray(arr, len(arr))
```

It's probably most sensible to define a little function to do the job, e.g.:

```
import ctypes

lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("./main.so")
lib.CTestArray.restype = None

def CTestArray(l):
    arr = (ctypes.c_double * len(l))(*l)
    lib.CTestArray.argtypes = [type(arr), ctypes.c_int]
    lib.CTestArray(arr, len(arr))

CTestArray([1, 3, .5, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, .5, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1])
CTestArray([42, 3.1415])
CTestArray([i/2 for i in range(40)])
```

Of course, at this point, setting the argument types at all is a little silly.

Comment: @ShakibaZar: oops, I forgot to update that part of the code sample after testing: that should just be `float64`.